# How to create folder with an icon for Finder?

Tags: macos, icons, finder

How do I create a folder with an icon for Finder (like I do it with the Dropbox installer)?

[image]

It's also interesting to know, how do I do it as user - not a programmer? Are there any tools for that?

Comment: You should probably ask this on super user since it's not a programming question.

Comment: I don't think not programming method exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that the Finder is using gray icons in the sidebar, it doesn't pay attention to a folder's custom icon. Some folders, like Applications or Desktop, get special icons because the Finder knows they're special, but there is no way to tell the Finder about new types of special folders. I'm fairly certain Dropbox uses a code injection hack to force its own custom icon.

Comment: How to add the same new code injection hack?

Comment: You can use the mach_inject library <https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_inject> to do the code injection. From there, you have to figure out how the sidebar list is being drawn so you can override the necessary methods. Honestly, I don't recommend it because it can break with any Finder update.

Answer (score 1):

Get info on the file in the Finder, click to select the file's icon, then use Paste to paste an image.

You might be able to use AppleScript to get the Finder to do it for you.

You might also look at [Candy Bar](http://www.panic.com/blog/2012/08/candybar-mountain-lion-and-beyond) (it's free, but unsupported).

Comment: This doesn't work for gray Finder icons.

Comment: what do you mean grey? in the sidebar?

Comment: Yes, look at the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

For Lion and Mountain Lion, you can use [Side Effects](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/43078/sideeffects) which restores color icons to the Finder sidebar.

At that point, there are two routes.

For something DropBox in your example or Google Drive, it should already pick up the custom icon on its own, and there's nothing else you have to do.

[image]

For other folders you may wish to customize (or any other item you may wish to drag into your sidebar, from an app to a document), if you have a custom icon you would prefer to see, you can substitute it your self by performing `Get Info` on the item of interest, then clicking on the icon in that panel, and then performing a context-menu **Paste**, and your custom icon will appear for that item.

Comment: I already tried it. It breaks original image - it shows it very smoothly and ugly. Also it replaces all system icons - not only for my folders. Color icons are very ugly:(

Comment: not sure what you mean by "it breaks original image".  which image are you saying it shows "smoothly and ugly"?  isn't smooth a good thing?  also, ugly is in the eye of the beholder, i guess.  i find the gray icons a step back in terms of functional usability, and gray has always said "disabled" to me in terms of UI design.

Comment: 1. Add original gray icons to Side Effects. They will be ugly. 2. Add original color (!) icons to Side Effects. They will be ugly much more. So, it's very bad way. And I want to replace icons only for my folders.